# Understanding the UNPAIR syntactic sugar

Tags: michelson

```
UNP(\left=A|P(\left)(\right))(\right=I|P(\left)(\right))R: A syntactic sugar for destructing nested pairs. These macros follow the same convention as the previous one.
> UNPAIR / S => DUP ; CAR ; DIP { CDR } / S
> UNPA(\right)R / S => UNPAIR ; DIP (UN(\right)R) / S
> UNP(\left)IR / S => UNPAIR ; UN(\left)R / S
> UNP(\left)(\right)R => UNPAIR ; UN(\left)R ; UN(\right)R / S
```

When I read this, sometimes `UNP(\left)IR` is used, other times `UN(\left)R` is used.  I'm not sure how to interpret an `UNP(\left)(\right)R`.  If an example like

```
P A  P P A  I    I R
( l, ( ( l, r ), r ))
```

was provided I think it would be much clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a user, you can understand it in exactly the same way as the P*R macro. You only need to decode the `\left`/`\right` notation there if you want to understand the implementation.

Here is an example:

```
UNIT :d; UNIT :c; UNIT :b; UNIT :a;
PAPPAIIR; # (pair (unit :a) (pair (pair (unit :b) (unit :c)) (unit :d))) : S
UNPAPPAIIR; # (unit :a) : (unit :b) : (unit :c) : (unit :d) : S
```

The pair structure associated with PAPPAIIR and UNPAPPAIIR is the same, `(a, ((b, c), d))`. UNPAPPAIIR just operates in the reverse direction.

To understand the implementation/specification there, you need to read `\left` and `\right` as variables, bound on the left of `=>` and substituted into the right of `=>`.

Comment: makes sense, although I think there's a typo with `UNP(\left)IR` and `UN(\left)R` both being used

Comment: That is not a typo. However, the spec does appear to have some mistakes. And in any case, it does not match the real implementation.